# Inconsistency between unattended-upgrade and debsecan

Tags: updates, software-recommendation, security

To install security updates automatically I use [`unattended-upgrade`](https://askubuntu.com/a/412/349837):

```
$ sudo unattended-upgrade -d | tail -1
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

I also tried [another tool called `debsecan`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35825436/4970442) ([homepage](https://security-team.debian.org/security_tracker.html), currently on official repos) to list all packages with any vulnerability of [CVE database](https://cve.mitre.org/). On a recently updated Ubuntu 18.04 LTS it returns 967 "remotely exploitable, high urgency" vulnerabilities on 220 packages (7 times more in total):

```
$ debsecan | grep "remotely exploitable, high urgency" | wc -l
967
$ debsecan | grep "remotely exploitable, high urgency" | col2 | uniq | wc -l
220
$ debsecan | grep -o "CVE-20[0-2][0-9]" | sort | uniq -c
    3 CVE-2007
    2 CVE-2008
    8 CVE-2009
    3 CVE-2012
   14 CVE-2013
    9 CVE-2014
   42 CVE-2015
  173 CVE-2016
  948 CVE-2017
 3616 CVE-2018
 4158 CVE-2019
 3540 CVE-2020
    1 CVE-2021
```

1. Am I missing something?
2. There is any tool to check for vulnerabilities, maybe a *debsecan for Ubuntu*, like Red Hat's [OpenSCAP](https://www.open-scap.org/) (now available! See below). Any other beside OpenVAS or Nessus?

#### Updates

- 2019: Answer from someone on Ubuntu Security Team:

  > In Ubuntu, [landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/) is the preferred solution for checking security update status.
  >
  > We would certainly like for someone to contribute the modifications required to get debsecan working. Here is the bug about debsecan.
  >
  > [debsecan should be either adjusted (for ubuntu) or removed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debsecan/+bug/95925)
- [Seems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113429/inconsistency-between-unattended-upgrade-and-debsecan#comment1838202_1113430) `debsecan` read this file:

  ```
  curl -s https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/debsecan/release/1/GENERIC | zlib-flate -uncompress | less
  ```

  AFAIK (please correct me) since [there is no API](https://askubuntu.com/a/169578/349837) for Ubuntu Security Advisory (USN), the data from [CVE-tracking page](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/) or [USN](https://usn.ubuntu.com/) (<del>or maybe easier from [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-security/ubuntu-cve-tracker/master/files/head:/active/)</del>, everything on bazaar.launchpad.net seems removed) should be merged [*into a JSON and*] there.
- **[2020-05](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debsecan/+bug/95925/comments/12)**: UST2DSA

  > We've just finished a tool to build debsecan suitable databases from the Ubuntu CVE Tracker data.
  > It is open source under Apache 2.0 and it is available here: https://github.com/BBVA/ust2dsa
  > Using Github's CI we rebuild the databases every 6 hours for them to contain the latest vulnerability information.
  > If anybody want to test the result you just have to run this command in your current Ubuntu installation:
  > `debsecan --suite $(lsb_release --codename --short) --source https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BBVA/ust2dsa/data/`
- **2021-11**: [Ubuntu’s OVAL data](https://ubuntu.com/security/oval) using [OpenSCAP](https://www.open-scap.org/tools/openscap-base/#download)

  ```sh
  sudo apt install libopenscap8  # Install OpenSCAP base

  wget https://security-metadata.canonical.com/oval/com.ubuntu.$(lsb_release -cs).usn.oval.xml.bz2
  bunzip2 com.ubuntu.$(lsb_release -cs).usn.oval.xml.bz2
  oscap oval eval --report report.html com.ubuntu.$(lsb_release -cs).usn.oval.xml
  xdg-open report.html
  ```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/*-release`? You maybe on an usupported version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tl;DR**: `debsecan` needs to be fixed to use Ubuntu's security tracker for it to be of any use on Ubuntu.

---

The `debsecan` script only checks the Debian Security Tracker, and only supports Debian releases in the `--suite` options. Since patched versions of Ubuntu packages don't show up in Debian's tracker, we get results like this:

```
$  debsecan | grep "remotely exploitable, high urgency" | head
CVE-2017-14632 libvorbisfile3 (remotely exploitable, high urgency)
CVE-2016-2776 bind9-host (remotely exploitable, high urgency)
CVE-2017-14930 binutils-dev (remotely exploitable, high urgency)
CVE-2017-8421 binutils-dev (remotely exploitable, high urgency)
CVE-2018-8784 libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (remotely exploitable, high urgency)
...
```

I'm on 16.04, and of these CVEs:

- [CVE-2017-14632](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-14632.html) is fix-released in 16.04
- [CVE-2016-2776](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-2776.html) is fix-released in 16.04
- [CVE-2017-14930](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-14930.html) needs triage in 16.04, and newer releases are marked not affected.
- [CVE-2017-8421](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-8421.html) needs triage
- and [CVE-2018-8784](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-8784.html) does not exist in 16.04.

So, of the first five I looked at, three were fixed or didn't affect me, one had some action taken and only one hadn't seen any action. The next five, CVE-2018-8785 through 2018-8789, were all fix-released or not affecting 16.04.

Comment: Thank you! So you think there is nothing I should worry about? So does make sens to have debsecan there on Ubuntu repos? There is any _debsecan for Ubuntu_? Or just alternative ways to make basic security checks.

Comment: @PabloBianchi I think if the Ubuntu Security Team would offer debsecan data on their site, the tool could work. I checked [the file it accesses](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/debsecan/release/1/GENERIC) and it's a fairly simple CSV file (zlib compressed). https://security.stackexchange.com/q/187909 says there's no built-in way to get easily parsed data from Ubuntu, so maybe such a tool doesn't exist for Ubuntu now.